# Why does the universal janitor have work for thousands of years?

Tags: science-based, geopolitics

So, if you're familiar with *Avatar: The Last Airbender*, you probably know what I'm talking about.

You have a powerful person who can reincarnate and who's sole purpose is to maintain balance between at least four nations, and thus, is a meddling do-gooder who cannot just watch the N-words incinerate J-words, unlike a certain superpower.

Now, I don't remember any avatar at least trying to establish a political system that would have helped <s>Montesquieu</s> maintain <s>Montesquieu</s> balance by <s>Montesquieu</s> design and <s>Montesquieu</s> considering an overwhelming majority of the problems are caused by humans, white supremacists, egalitarians, anarchists, authoritarian laser cannons  <s>and Montesquieu</s>; that didn't really make a whole lot of sense.

But again, I also forgot that I was watching MHA, so don't take my word for that.

So, we're looking for a fundamental reason why this very powerful person decided not to involve themselves in politics (as in being a member of a party or ruling over anything). And this reason has to be so fundamental, so engraved in the system that it would stay valid for thousands of years. What could that reason be?

Comment: Is it correct that your question is only about the _motives_ of such person, while the _means_ of achieving geopolitical goal from a lowly position should be taken for granted?

Answer (score 3):

Simple.

*They’re one person*

They know that no matter what they try their loyal ministers will become corrupt, their sensibly designed senate will eventually shred itself, their brutal dictatorship will be overthrown. As they’re only one (admittedly powerful) person they can only ever hope to exert temporary control or provide momentary balance. And after the fall of whatever governmental system they put in place/design/espouse/rule over with an iron fist they inevitably find that their ability to keep balance by more traditional means (POW, WHAP, KUNG-FU) is diminished due to the aftereffects of them trying to get involved in politics. The once loyal ministers enact laws making them an outlaw. The Senate ties them up in pointless red tape. The Rebels galvanise the public into uniting against them.

Therefore: it is better to remain aloof, and instead apply the minimum force at the optimum time to curb the worst imbalances without ever getting too involved. That way the next time they need to KAPOW some threat away they aren’t simultaneously fending off their (now nefarious, shocker) grand vizier.

Basically: They’ve already failed at politics so many times they find it easier to not try anymore.

Answer (score 3):

**Politics is a Human Thing**

To continue with the *Avatar* example, maintaining the balance of the world is more than just making sure that the humans that live in it don't off each other in a war that will destabilize the natural harmony of humanity.  It is making sure that humans don't completely devastate the natural world, the spiritual world, or do something that will break the balance of the world as a whole.

Were the Cosmic Janitor to get involved in politics, then they would be locked into what are, for the most part, purely *human* struggles.  In essence, they have already picked humanity over the rest of the world's inhabitants.  And if they actually haven't, it will at least look like they have.  That could rapidly become an issue if your domain is the entire world.

Also, by miring themselves in human politics, they have mired themselves in all of the rules and power-plays of the domain.  Yes, you could make a system in one generation that is designed to help humanity maintain the balance in the world.  However it only takes one person powerful and driven enough to break that balance, and with it the system that was built to maintain it.  This could be as unsubtle as boosting kung-fu pyromancy through a flaming rock flying through space, or by something more subtle like a knife between the shoulder blades.

Also, you reincarnate.  Unless you directly reincarnate into another immediately useful body, there are going to be at least a decade where you are out of the picture and with a power vacuum comes opportunists that will try to fill it in their way.  Doubly so if they can mold your reincarnated child mind to your cause.

Miring yourself solely in Human affairs also means that you might not be available to mediate in non-human affairs, such as territory disputes between non-human entities.  This can present the image that you do not care about non-humans which potentially affects the balance of the world negatively by your own actions, which should mean that you have to address that imbalance as well.

By removing yourself from the political system, you have freedom to move both within it and outside of it.  Words can be quite good at deescalating conflict and a outside neutral party might be just what is needed to keep harmony.  At the same time, as the Cosmic Janitor, you might need to get your adamantine mop out and start hitting things with it until it stops being a problem, then mop up the remains to keep the world clean.  Also, your attempts at mediation will not be tainted with the thought that whatever you help negotiate will ultimately be better for the humans that you have attached yourself to.